# How would I compare the two to properly sort in order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Objective is to distinguish the two arrays, and console log the products array in order by its price range, I tried using a nested for-loop to see if this can work out but hasn't gone off in the right track, was also thinking about using lo dash as well. How would I be able to compare the id's between the two and push them in order by price?

```
/*
 Your task is to write a function or set of functions that console logs out the products ordered by price
*/



var products = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Buzzy' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bytrex' },
  { id: 3, name: 'CactiDance' },
  { id: 4, name: 'CactiLoops' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Cadaver Jelly' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Caffeine Serene' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Cajun Sation' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Call it Green' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Callflex' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Calling Card Shark' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Calque' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Camel Meal Tea' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Camelot Chamomile' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Campxotica' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Camus the Killer Tale' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Candecor' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Candelarium' },
  { id: 18, name: 'CandID' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Candlelight Vittles' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Candy Ask' },
  { id: 21, name: 'Candy Floss' },
];

var prices = [
  { id: 6, price: 55 },
  { id: 14, price: 22 },
  { id: 15, price: 57 },
  { id: 4, price: 41 },
  { id: 18, price: 9 },
  { id: 17, price: 3 },
  { id: 2, price: 73 },
  { id: 7, price: 43 },
  { id: 5, price: 78 },
  { id: 1, price: 91 },
  { id: 8, price: 58 },
  { id: 16, price: 69 },
  { id: 13, price: 74 },
  { id: 19, price: 14 },
  { id: 21, price: 25 },
  { id: 12, price: 84 },
  { id: 20, price: 8 },
  { id: 9, price: 94 },
  { id: 10, price: 36 },
  { id: 3, price: 34 },
  { id: 11, price: 71 },
];
```

Comment: Why would you have 2 arrays for this? Why not have 1 array and populate the price when you know it. Initialize it as 0. Then when you know the price, sort by price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the `prices` array first. Then loop through it and get the `products` for each `id` using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```js
var products = [{id:1,name:"Buzzy"},{id:2,name:"Bytrex"},{id:3,name:"CactiDance"},{id:4,name:"CactiLoops"},{id:5,name:"Cadaver Jelly"},{id:6,name:"Caffeine Serene"},{id:7,name:"Cajun Sation"},{id:8,name:"Call it Green"},{id:9,name:"Callflex"},{id:10,name:"Calling Card Shark"},{id:11,name:"Calque"},{id:12,name:"Camel Meal Tea"},{id:13,name:"Camelot Chamomile"},{id:14,name:"Campxotica"},{id:15,name:"Camus the Killer Tale"},{id:16,name:"Candecor"},{id:17,name:"Candelarium"},{id:18,name:"CandID"},{id:19,name:"Candlelight Vittles"},{id:20,name:"Candy Ask"},{id:21,name:"Candy Floss"}],
   prices = [{id:6,price:55},{id:14,price:22},{id:15,price:57},{id:4,price:41},{id:18,price:9},{id:17,price:3},{id:2,price:73},{id:7,price:43},{id:5,price:78},{id:1,price:91},{id:8,price:58},{id:16,price:69},{id:13,price:74},{id:19,price:14},{id:21,price:25},{id:12,price:84},{id:20,price:8},{id:9,price:94},{id:10,price:36},{id:3,price:34},{id:11,price:71}];

prices.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      .forEach(p => {
        console.log(products.find(a => a.id === p.id))
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` & `findIndex`. `map` will return a new array. Inside the callback function of `map` use `findIndex` and use it to find the index of the object where the id matches.

```js
var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Buzzy'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bytrex'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'CactiDance'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'CactiLoops'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Cadaver Jelly'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Caffeine Serene'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Cajun Sation'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Call it Green'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Callflex'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Calling Card Shark'
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: 'Calque'
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Camel Meal Tea'
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: 'Camelot Chamomile'
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: 'Campxotica'
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    name: 'Camus the Killer Tale'
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    name: 'Candecor'
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    name: 'Candelarium'
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    name: 'CandID'
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    name: 'Candlelight Vittles'
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: 'Candy Ask'
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    name: 'Candy Floss'
  },
];

var prices = [{
    id: 6,
    price: 55
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    price: 22
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    price: 57
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    price: 41
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    price: 9
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    price: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: 73
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    price: 43
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    price: 78
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 91
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    price: 58
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    price: 69
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    price: 74
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    price: 14
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    price: 25
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    price: 84
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    price: 8
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    price: 94
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    price: 36
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    price: 34
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    price: 71
  },
];



let newArr = prices.map(function(item) {
  let k = products.findIndex(elem => elem.id === item.id);
  if (k !== -1) {
    return products[k]
  }

});
console.log(newArr)
```